# Pinch zoom to arbitrary level like in Windows

Tags: touchpad, browser, zooming

In Windows, I can pinch on the touchpad to zoom to arbitrary levels within a browser window (Chrome, Edge, Firefox), and it doesn't invoke the browser's page zoom. This is something I use heavily and am missing badly in Ubuntu, Kubuntu, LinuxMint and all the other Linux distros I have ever tried.

Is there any way to do something similar in Ubuntu, or any other distro for that matter?

Comment: **Update:** I think this works if the distro is using Wayland. I am not 100% sure though.